# Engine Yard error related to postgress and socket '/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, engineyard

I have a rails application hosted on Engine Yard Cloud. After deploy I am getting an error:

> Process postgresql: POSTGRES_CONNECTION CRITICAL: DB 'postgres' could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket '/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432'

After this error the instance with the application become unreachable and reloading the instance is required. After reloading the instance I can deploy once, but with the next deploy I am getting the same error. I would appreciate any ideas on how to solve this.

Comment: Are you on Mac OS X by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause of this condition is that the Postgres server has stopped responding. This most commonly occurs due to a low memory condition on Solo instances but can have other causes as well. The best way to explore this further is to [file a ticket](https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/tickets/new) with the Engine Yard Support team and we can investigate this further for you.

Thank you,
Tyler